# C# coding to add a value to a text box according to a combo box using a database

Tags: c#

I wrote this code to change the value in my cmbChild combo box according to the changing values in cmbParent combo box. Now I have another text box called "price" to display the price of the products which are shown in cmbChild combo box. I have a database table called "table" which have two columns called brand & price. I can find cmbChild combo box items in brand column. I need to change the value in the textbox when customers select different names in cmbChild combo box. Please help me. My code is here. BT it doesn't work. It works upto textbox point but then it gives an error message about SQL coding.

` public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        listParent.Add("Chocolate");
        listParent.Add("Biscuit");
        listParent.Add("Milk");
        listParent.Add("Sugar");
        listParent.Add("Flour");
        listParent.Add("Ice Cream");

        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Kandos"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Edna"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Mars"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Rovello"));

        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Biscuit", "Maliban"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Biscuit", "Munchee"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Biscuit", "Maam"));

        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Anchor"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Nespray"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Raththi"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Lakspray"));

        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Sugar", "Arpico"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Sugar", "Cargils"));

        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Flour", "Prima"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Flour", "MDK"));

        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Ice Cream", "Elephant House"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Ice Cream", "Keels"));
        listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Ice Cream", "Highland"));



        foreach (var item in listParent)
        {
            cmbParent.Items.Add(item);
        }

        cmbParent.SelectedIndexChanged += CmbParent_SelectedIndexChanged;
        cmbChild.SelectedIndexChanged += CmbChild_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    List<String> listParent = new List<String>();
    List<Tuple<String, String>> listChild = new List<Tuple<String, String>>();


    private void CmbChild_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedBrand = (string)cmbChild.SelectedItem;

        //get data from database
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("[your connection string]");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;

        command.CommandText = "Select Price from [your table] where productBrand = @productBrand";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productBrand", selectedBrand);

        conn.Open();
        decimal price = (decimal)command.ExecuteScalar();

        txtPrice.Text = price.ToString();

        conn.Close();
    }

    private void CmbParent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Tuple<String, String>> productsList = new List<Tuple<String, String>>();
        productsList = listChild.Where(x => x.Item1 == (string)cmbParent.SelectedItem).ToList();

        cmbChild.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in productsList)
        {
            cmbChild.Items.Add(item.Item2);
        };
    }`
```

Comment: Humans are not compilers. Take time to make it more readable.

Comment: Oh sorry that. I will post the code properly. It was posted like that by mistake

Comment: Now I added the code well. Please help me to write the code